# Updating select tag from database with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, select, explode

I have a table named 'item' in the database which has different columns, one of them named 'size' has two values separated by comma, i.e Medium, Large. Now When I'm retrieving those values to show in my 'select' tag it shows them together, I tried using explode(); but I'm messing up with its behavior. I have attached the pictures of the table and the resulted data inside my site along with the code.

[image]

> The while loop is implemented above, this is only the 'Size:' part

```
    Size :  
<?php var_dump($row["item_size"]);
$arr = $row["item_size"];  
$exp = explode("," , $arr);
var_dump($exp);

 ?>
      <select name="product_size">
<?php
echo "<option value='".$row["item_size"]."'>".$row["item_size"]."</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
```

[image]

Comment: should not store arrays in fields ( normalise your storage )

Comment: better way to do this is to store categories ( Medium, small, etc. ) in a table and have a link table between your products and this categories eg. product_cats. then you can join and retrieve this information ( and more when you change your requirements ) easily

Comment: If I've understood correctly, In that case, the link table product_cats could contain a product_id (in my case item_id) and a category column. Now Again, I will have to store a array in the category column If I want to store more than one category (Medium, Small) , no?

Comment: no. you will end up storing two records product_id: 10, cat_id: 1 ( Small )
and product_id: 10, cat_id: 2 ( Medium ). this structure can be joined on and analysed in simple way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the `size` array right after explode.

```
    $arr = $row["item_size"];  
    $exp = explode("," , $arr);

echo "<select name='product_size'>";

foreach($exp as $key=>$val) {
        echo "<option value='" . $val . "'>" . $val . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Working [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/anlwAb)